# Add a click listener on an item in a Pgination JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to add a listener to an item of a pagination that extract the selected item.

I have a class PaginationController in which contains my Paginaton, but the item   is on another class:
ItemController.

I want to be able to extract the info of an item when the user click on it in PaginationController Class.

this is my code :

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   refreshNodes() ; 
   p.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
        @Override
        public Node call(Integer index) {

            StackPane page = new StackPane();

            GridPane grid = new GridPane();

            grid.setHgap(20);
            grid.setVgap(20);
            grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

            int total = 10 ; 
            int rows = 2 ; 
            int cols = 2 ; 

            int offset = rows * cols * index;

            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

                    offset++;

                    if (offset > total)
                        break;

                    StackPane container = new StackPane();
                    container.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");

                    
                    container.getChildren().add(nodes[offset]);

                    GridPane.setRowIndex(container, row);
                    GridPane.setColumnIndex(container, col);
                    GridPane.setHgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);
                    GridPane.setVgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);

                    grid.getChildren().add(container);
                }
            }

            page.getChildren().add(grid);

            return page;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to make the Nodes in the GridPane clickable, and set up an EventHandler for those clicks that will export the data back to your pagination controller.  Don't think of the Nodes as data, but think of them as active elements that can do stuff.  Also, as much as possible don't rebuild your layout in response to clicks and user actions.  All you need to do is to repopulate your GridPane, you don't need to create a whole new one each page:

public class PaginationSample extends Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

Node[] nodes = new Node[100];
int index = 0;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new MainScreen(), 200, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    Consumer<String> nodeConsumer = nodeData -> System.out.println("Node data: " + nodeData);
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        nodes[x] = new NodeThing("Node " + x, nodeConsumer);
    }
    primaryStage.show();
}

class MainScreen extends BorderPane {

    MainScreen() {
        PageNode pageNode = new PageNode();
        setCenter(pageNode);
        Button nextButton = new Button("Next");
        nextButton.setOnAction(evt -> pageNode.loadPage(index++));
        Button prevButton = new Button("Previous");
        prevButton.setOnAction(evt -> pageNode.loadPage(index--));
        setBottom(new HBox(30, prevButton, nextButton));
    }
}

class NodeThing extends VBox {
    NodeThing(String nodeData, Consumer<String> dataReciever) {
        Button button = new Button("Button");
        button.setOnAction(evt -> dataReciever.accept(nodeData));
        getChildren().addAll(new Text(nodeData), button);
    }
}

class PageNode extends GridPane {

    PageNode() {
        setHgap(20);
        setVgap(20);
        setPadding(new Insets(20));
    }

    void loadPage(int index) {
        getChildren().clear();
        int rows = 2;
        int cols = 2;

        int offset = rows * cols * index;

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                if (offset++ >= nodes.length) {
                    break;
                }
                StackPane container = new StackPane();
                container.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white");
                container.getChildren().add(nodes[offset]);
                add(container, col, row);
                GridPane.setHgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);
                GridPane.setVgrow(container, Priority.ALWAYS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: don't extend layout classes - the general rule is the same as for all classes in OO: extend for adding new functionality only, otherwise configure and use.